# scss how do I use @ in a css class name

Tags: css, sass

I use gridle scss as a lightweight responsive grid system and when I build it, it creates classes like `gr-6@mobile`

So I was trying to come up with my own mobile class:

```css
.align-right {
  text-align: right;

  @include gridle-state(mobile) {
    &@mobile {
      text-align: right;
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't build so was just wondering how you use an `@` in a class name

Also tried the following but they don't work either:

```
&#{@mobile} {}          // wrapping it in #{}
.align-right@mobile {}  // putting it all in one line didn't like it either
```

Comment: You can escape it: `&\@mobile {...}`. Don't be surprise if the backslash is still there in your css output, it's normal and it works just fine.

Comment: Ah, thought it would be something simple.  If you add an answer, I can accept it.  Thanks

Comment: done, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a special character, you can escape it.
For your particular issue, you should write:

```
.align-right {
  text-align: right;

  @include gridle-state(mobile) {
    &\@mobile {
      text-align: right;
    }
  }
}
```

This will compile to:

```
.align-right\@mobile {...}
```

The backslash in your `.css` file is expected and will be rendered just fine in your browser.

To know more about escaping a character in sass, you can check [the docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/strings#escapes).

Comment: Thanks, you forgot to include the backslash in the answer so I just added it